# Is it possible to list all array sizes with list functions (without looping)?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, size, byte

I have a list with type `float[]`.
I never know how big the size of float array is but I need to know how big the size is for all the arrays together.

Example:

```
List<float[]> f = new List<float[]>();

f.Add(new float[3] { 1f, 5f, 1f });
f.Add(new float[5] { 1f, 5f, 1f, 1f,2f });
```

Both together should be 32 bytes, shouldn't they?
But how do I count it without looping? Can I do it with lambda or linq?

Another questions :
Is it also possible to merge both elements?

EDIT: What I mean is without `for/foreach while`

Comment: Do you think that LINQ doesn't need loops? You mean something like this: `float size = f.Sum(arr => arr.Sum()) // 17`

Comment: You have to loop over the list, but you don't have to loop over the arrays if you want the sum of the lengths of the arrays `f.Sum(a=>a.Length)`

Comment: Yea was looking for something like that.I know it is looping. What I wanted to say was just for "for/foreach-loops".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var size = f.Sum(a => a.Length);
var merged = f.SelectMany(a => a).ToList();
```